# spring integration with mule

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Can anyone help/point me in the right direction.

I have a timestamp column in MySQL and I want to select records matching a particular date , for example  all records created on e 2017-10-12.

The mysql records are as below

ID  NAME CREATEDON              STATUS
--  ---- ---------              ------
113 MALM 2017-10-12 11:40:00.0  PASSED
113 KYC  2017-10-12 02:20:00.0  PASSED

I tried

select * from ORDERS where CREATEDON='2017-10-12'

and also

select * from ORDERS where CREATEDON=unix_timestamp('2017-10-12')

both query returns NO records

Appreciate if someone can guide me on this

Thank you

Comment: You can try `select * from ORDERS where left(CREATEDON,10) = '2017-10-12'`

Comment: Thank  you, your solution works

Comment: Glad to help @jaya k :)